# Equivalence of flatMapMany and flatMap from Mono/Flux to Flow (Kotlin Coroutines)

Tags: spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to refactor this code:

```
fun getCharacterFilms(serverRequest: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    val films = starWarsApiWebClient.findCharacter(serverRequest.pathVariable("id").toInt())
            .flatMapMany { it.films.toFlux() }
            .flatMap(starWarsApiWebClient::findFilm)

    return ok().body(films, Film::class.java)
}
```

where:

```
fun findCharacter(id: Int): Mono<Character> {...}

fun findFilm(uri: URI): Mono<Film> {...}
```

but now with Flow:

```
fun findCharacter(id: Int) = webClient.baseUrl("https://swapi.co/api/").build()
            .get().uri("/people/$id/")
            .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).retrieve()
            .bodyToFlow<Character>()

fun findFilm(uri: URI): Flow<Film> {
    val webClient = WebClient.builder()
    return webClient.build()
            .get().uri(uri)
            .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).retrieve()
            .bodyToFlow<Film>()
}
```

There is no problem with:

```
suspend fun getCharacter(serverRequest: ServerRequest) = ok().bodyAndAwait(starWarsApiWebClient.findCharacter(serverRequest.pathVariable("id").toInt()))
```

but I don't know how to translate these flatMapMany and flatMap.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
suspend fun getCharacterFilms(serverRequest: ServerRequest) = ok()
        .bodyAndAwait(starWarsApiWebClient.findCharacter(serverRequest.pathVariable("id").toInt())
                .flatMapMerge {
                    it.films.asFlow()
                }.flatMapMerge {
                    starWarsApiWebClient.findFilm(it)
                })
```

Comment: flatMapMerge (instead of flatMapConcat in this case) better, I'm going to update my answser